# Check if object is of type (type is defined as array) - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

Let's say I have this

```
export type Hash = [ hashtype, hash ];

export type hashtype = -16 | -43 | 5 | 6;
export type hash = Buffer;
```

I want to write something that will check whether an object is a Hash

**not implemented**

```
isHash = (obj: any) => {
    return (obj is Hash) // pseudo code, to implement
}
```

So that I would have such a return:

```
isHash(5)                         => false    //  no hash
isHash([25, <Buffer ad 30>])      => false    //  25 is not in hashType

isHash([5, <Buffer ad 30>])       => true     //  valid
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a general-purpose way to check whether a type matches. For your specific case, I would do something like this:

```
const isHash = (obj: unknown): obj is Hash => {
  if (!Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (obj.length !== 2) {
    return false;
  }
  return [-16, -43, 5, 6].includes(obj[0]) && Buffer.isBuffer(obj[1]);
}
```

Comment: You can just directly `return` all of those conditions infixed by `&&` if you invert the first two.

Comment: You seem to have deleted your last comment in between my reading it and preparing this playground link to send in response to it: https://tsplay.dev/W4yMAw

Comment: Yeah, i deleted it because it was just an opinion question, so it doesn't really matter. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I'll just stick to that for now then. Maybe if I get around to it and it's not too complex, I can write an auto-generator :D